LaTeX rendering in source mode but can't knit pdf
I am getting an error with LaTeX saying "You may need to add $ $ around a certain inline expression". The text renders correctly when I look at it in the source mode but I can't knit it.
I tried loading tinytex but it didn't make a difference. I also wrote
output:  pdf_document: latex_engine: xelatex in the header but it didn't change anything. I ended up rewriting it in the visual mode on RStudio but I basically copy and pasted what I had before and finally got it to work.

always show code in a text block so people can reproduce the problem. But you can not have blank lines in math mode nor linebreaks from \\  in $$ display math

I also wonder if there is an issue with the rmarkdown preprocessor here, which may or may not be related to what David wrote. The error message suggests that the preprocessor is escaping the dollar signs changing $$ to \$\$. This could be because the extra paragraph break you inserted confused it.

Please add a minimal working example so people can work with it to help you solve your problem. You may need to add a tex codeblock tag around your tex/latex code. I had to do that on a noteblock to make it display correctly on pdf.

This render perfectly in rmarkdown:
Foo $$ \theta 
\beta $$ bar

While this will produce that error:
Foo $$ \theta 

\beta $$ bar

With the result:
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.72 Foo \$\$ \theta ... 

But the primary problem is not that $$ is  misunderstand  as plain text. As David pointed, the real issue is that you cannot have blank lines in math mode, while escaping the dollar signs is only the side effect of not having a valid block of LaTeX code.
This is the same case that if you type \begin{center} foo \end{enter} (note the typo). This will be exported "as is" in the pdf. The problem seems to be that Pandoc cannot recognize the LaTeX environment, but the true issue is that there are not any  environment (center is open, but not closed), so Pandoc cannot  (and should not) consider this as a chunk of raw LaTeX code.
This is clear marking the math part as raw LaTeX ...

Foo 
```{=latex}
$$ \theta 

\beta $$ 
```
bar

... so you will avoid  the escaping of the dollars, but you still will have a  "Missing $ inserted" just like in:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$$ \theta 

\beta $$ 
\end{document}

